# ARGV arguments syntax in DBI

Tags: perl, dbi, argv

I am trying to connect to different instances of oracle databases by passing values through the DBI command but still can't. What I am using now is:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:'$ARGV[0]'','XXXXXXXXXXX', '$ARGV[1]')
or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

I tried printing ARGV[0] and ARGV[1] and it's giving me syntax errors even when I try different combinations of ' & ". Am i doing something evidently wrong here? Also want to point out that when I actually replace this with the values I do get connected so I am definitely using the '"' wrong.

Comment: Why not `("dbi:Oracle:$ARGV[0]", …)`?  The pair of adjacent single quotes is a little pointless anyway, isn't it, being intended to concatenate an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

`.` is the concatenation operator.

```
DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:' . $ARGV[0], 'XXXXXXXXXXX', $ARGV[1])
```

or even

```
DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$ARGV[0]", 'XXXXXXXXXXX', $ARGV[1])
```

By the way, you shouldn't pass passwords on the command line since they can be seen by other users on the machine.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I have stored passwords in a shell script which I am using to run the perl script.

Comment: You could use an environment var (e.g. `PASSWORD=foo perl -E'say $ENV{PASSWORD}'`), or pipe it in via STDIN